# scroll only one div while the other is fixed, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a web page, am using bootstrap-4 also. The page is divided into two columns, using divs. I need the right side of the div to scroll and the left side to stand still. I've tried using 'over-flow' but its not working, like when I'm scrolling down the left side div comes with it. As I said I've used bootstrap,

I've a base div which holds the class 'container-fluid' and inside it another div which holds the class 'row' and my two divs come inside this div. it is as follows:

```
<body>
 <div class=container-fluid>
  <div class=row>
   <div class="col-md-3 pt-5 align-items-center back-color1 vh-100 overflow-hidden">
      <img>
      <p></p>
      <h3></h3>
      <div>
         (for nav-btns..)
         <p></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9 back-color2 overflow-auto">
     <div class="vh-100">
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
      <a></a>
      <div> (space for img.) </div>
     </div>
     <div class="vh-100">
       (this div for other contents on the page. This has to come down)
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

'overflow' not working on the code, don't know why

Comment: have you taken a try with the sticky-top class ? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#sticky-top

Comment: sticky-top class works, but it is causing problem when the screen size reduced to its minimum. The left-side comes on top and the scroll won't work hence making the contents hide forever @G-Cyrillus

Comment: If sticky-top works, but not for small screens, you may use the breakpoints https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#responsive-sticky-top (to unstick) and/or set other styles for smaller screens ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the position of the left div as fixed. Should give you the effect you want.

Add `position-fixed` to your class of the left div. This should do the trick.

Comment: position-fixed is making the div to expand and the entire alignment is destroying, do you have any suggestions on making it back to normal

Comment: @akarjun313 you need to restructure your site then. I don't have any other suggestion on making it fixed but you can search the internet for some. To structure your site I would add wrapper div which gets 100% of the pagewidth. Then you make your two divs and give them 50% width each. The fixed div needs 100% pageheigth as well. If your site still isn't structured well you could just set a margin on the right div of 50%. There are many ways, choose what is best for you.